# Is there any code # cmd powershell to change Lync call forwarding setting to new number?

Tags: c#, powershell, lync

Im looking for any powershell or c# code to integrate into my c# program. The require fuction is trigger change lync forwarding to new mobile number.
Anyone can help please?

Comment: Can you post a some of your code so we can help us answer. Also, your question is a little confusing. "_The require fuction is trigger change lync_" I'm not following.

Comment: I'm using below code to Lync call a given number.
I try to looking for any code can help me switch Lync call forwarding to another given number. thanks

Comment: try
            {
                string PhoneNumber = strPhoneNumber;
                LyncClient lyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient();
                var automation = LyncClient.GetAutomation();
                var conversationSettings = new Dictionary<AutomationModalitySettings, object>();
                List<string> participants = new List<string>();
                participants.Add(PhoneNumber);
                automation.BeginStartConversation(AutomationModalities.Audio, participants, null, null, null);
            }

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps based on what I understood from your question, you can modify and try...

**Options 1**:

Use the following powershell command / play around with options

1. To create the un/assigned number range, (or you can do it for just one number)
2. Then assign your forward/announcement to the un/assigned number range. You should also be to do this via the Skype for Business Control Panel.

   `New-CsUnassignedNumber -Identity 
     “Unassigned Number Range” -NumberRangeStart “+91344000” -NumberRangeEnd ““+91344002” 
    -AnnouncementName “Forward Announcement” -AnnouncementService 
     ApplicationServer:Skype.skypedevlabs.tykt.org`

---

**Option 2**: `SEFAUtil`

Use the the [Lync/Skype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/deploy/deploy-enterprise-voice/deploy-the-sefautil-tool?redirectedfrom=MSDN) Resource Kit installed and have deployed SEFAUTIL as a CSTrustedApplication (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj945659.aspx)

If the Lync/Skype (for newer versions) user already has a Call forwarding number set up you can change it

```
sefautil /server:poolname.domain.com
SIPAddressOfUser@tykt.org
/setfwddestination:+18000000
```

If the user doesnt have call forward, you can turn it on:

```
sefautil /server:poolname.domain.com
SIPAddressOfUser@tykt.org
/setfwddestination:+18000000 /enablefwdimmediate
```

If you want to disable call forwarding completely:

```
sefautil /server:poolname.domain.com
SIPAddressOfUser@sip.tykt.org /disablefwdimmediate
```

I also attached the link to download the Utility above!